# BitBlt not able to capture the title bar correctly

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, gdi+, gdi

I am using the code below to capture a screenshot of a window using bltblt. However the titlebar appears  completely black in the captured screenshot. I am running the code on Windows 8.1. Is there a way i can correctly capture the title bar.

```
// Retrieve the handle to a display device context for the sourceWindow
hdcScreen = GetDC(ss);
// Retrieve the handle to a display device context for the dest window
hdcWindow = GetDC(hWnd);

//Get the client area for size calculation
RECT rcClient;
GetWindowRect(ss, &rcClient);

if (!BitBlt(hdcWindow,
    0, 0,
    rcClient.right - rcClient.left, rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top,
    hdcScreen,
    0, 0,
    SRCCOPY|CAPTUREBLT))
{
    MessageBox(hWnd, L"BitBlt has failed", L"Failed", MB_OK);
    goto done;
}
```

[image: Screenshot, the title bar is highlighted by a read rectangular box.]

EDIT:
The window i am displaying the screenshot in would cover the entire desktop and will be constantly updating the screenshot of the window just behind it. Also, the window displaying the screenshot will always be the topmost window.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149271/how-to-correctly-screencapture-a-specific-window-on-aero-dwm may be of interest.

Comment: i checked it out..unfortunately that wont work for me as the window i am displaying the screenshot in would be covering the entire screen so i cant capture the entire desktop and  crop it to include the window i want in my screenshot.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [DWM thumbnails](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969541(v=vs.85).aspx) instead.

Comment: I need the pixel data as well..thats not possible with `DWM`thumbnail.

Comment: Why not just capture the client area, and put it into your own standard, maximized window, with the same titlebar text? You would need additional work to handle things like minimize, etc, but the effect would (possibly) be the same.

Comment: different window will have different title bar(the one in the screenshot has four buttons on the left hand side also) so it wont be feasible plus it wont work if i want to show more than one window in the screenshot...beside the window i will be showing the screenshot i wont have any titel bar or frame border

Answer (score 0):

The information you want is not all available from the window DC. Themes get painted over the top.

If you want an exactly visual representation you need to find the screen coordinates of the window (or part of it) and then blit from the screen DC.

---

If the window is not displayed, you may have an insurmountable problem. As far as I know the theme (since at least Windows Vista) is not part of the Window DC but is painted over the top using non-GDI techniques. The GDI simply does not have the capabilities to paint sophisticated blends and transparency effect. Until Windows 8 it was still possible to select the old classic themes but now they're gone. You may find that the title bar simply isn't painted in the NCPAINT handler any more.

Comment: the desktop screen will be covered in its entirety by the window i will be displaying and constantly updating the screenshot in...so the desktop screen will only return my own window displaying the screenshot.

Comment: You should edit your question -- this is critical information which you omitted to mention. How do you know what the window 'really' looks like if you've covered it up?

Comment: i edited my question..i will just be displaying the window immediately behind the window displaying the screenshot...also the window displaying the screenshot will always be the topmost window.

Comment: there will always be a window to display in the 'ScreenCapture' window as the Desktop is always visible(just the wallpaper part if there are no other windows on top of the desktop)...also is there a way to get the current theme and paint it manually over whatever is captured via BitBlt?I can probably store a bitmap with the just the title bar and the frame and transparent client area and AlphaBlend it with the WindowDC screenshot but that can be really slow especially since i am thinking of displaying all visible windows behind the ScreenCapture window, not just the one immediately behind it.

Comment: There is a whole API dedicated to themes but if that's the issue, that would be a new question.

Comment: the intent is still the same..capture the screenshot with title bar correctly even if requires some post processing using themes API..I will look into the themes API